# Android unable to open file after download

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-file, android-download-manager, download-manager

I am downloading a pdf file using DownloadManager class. It works fine on a Huawei GRA-L09 with android 5.0.1 **but** on my Nexus 6p with android 7.1.1 I experience the following behavior:

After the file is downloaded I try to open it via intent Action_View so it will be opened with pdf viewer. But when I try to open it I got an error that the file size is 0 and cannot be opened. If I wait about 10 seconds I am able to open the file.

This is the source code of DownloadManager:

```
DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));  request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/Download", "test.pdf");
long enqueue = dm.enqueue(request);
```

This is the source code of the BroadcastReceiver:

```
private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {
            DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query();
            query.setFilterById(enqueue);
            Cursor cursor = null;
            String uri = null;
            String mime = null;
            try {
                cursor = downloadManager.query(query);

                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    int status = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS));
                    if (status == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL) {
                        // process download
                        uri = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI));
                        mime = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_MEDIA_TYPE));
                    }
                }
            } finally {
                if (cursor != null) {
                    cursor.close();
                }
            }

            openFile(Uri.parse(uri), mime);
        }
    }
}; 

private void openFile(final Uri fileLocation, final String mimeType) {
    Intent objIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    objIntent.setDataAndType(fileLocation, mimeType);
    Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Downloaded file Uri: " + fileLocation.toString() + " mime:" + mimeType);
    objIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(objIntent, getString(R.string.choose_application));
    startActivity(chooserIntent);//Starting the pdf viewer
}
```

I tried opening it without the intent for pdf, just by pressing the notification icon on the status bar. The same thing happens, as if the file is locked or not downloaded yet.

**UPDATE**: On the Nexus device I get file size = 0 when i check file.length() after the download is completed. On the Huawei GRA-L09 the file size is 1882670.
So why do I get Download completed broadcast for a file with size 0?